# How to add menuitem to menulist using add-on sdk programmatically?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have defined a menulist in package.json:-

```
"preferences": [{
                "name": "editor_url",
                "title": "Editor URL:",
                "type": "menulist",
                "value": 0,
                "options": [
                        {
                            "value": "0",
                            "label": "http://localhost:53421"
                        }
                  ]
            }]
```

How can we add options/menuitems to the menulist dynamically?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To your `"options"` array I added:

```
{
    "value": "1",
    "label": "https://miskatonic.edu"
}
```

Then I tried the following as `lib/main.js`:

```
var preferences = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs:

console.log(JSON.stringify(preferences));
preferences.editor_url = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(preferences));
```

It didn't update the preferences display in Add-Ons Manager in real time, but after closing and re-opening preferences for the add-on, the other URL was displayed.